# Pass a org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject encoded string to a web service method

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, asn.1

So far this is my code but i dont know how to proceed

```
var theBytes = getSignedBytesFrom("Some string");
var ci = new ContentInfo( theBytes );
var signedCms = new SignedCms( ci );

var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner( myCert );
signedCms.ComputeSignature( cmsSigner );
signedCms.Encode();

//I dont know how to encode as org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1TaggedObject 
var ASN1TaggedObject = ?

var result = Convert.ToBase64String( ASN1TaggedObject ); 
var wsResponse = webs.passCms( result );
```

Please advice.

Comment: This documentation could be of some use to you 

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/a54f8e2b-1be0-a8de-d52b-d6eeed9a71ce.htm 

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Answer (score 0):

`ASN1TaggedObject` extends `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Encodable` which provides the following methods:

- `GetDerEncoded():byte[]` - returns the DER representation of the object.
- `GetEncoded():byte[]` - returns the BER representation of the object.
- `GetEncoded(string):byte[]` - the DER or BER representation depending on the parameter value (should be either `"DER"` or `"BER"`).

Unless you hove some specific requirements you should use `GetDerEncoded()` to convert the `Asn1Encodable` object into binary representation.